# Bootstrap column alignment on resizing browser window

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want 6-column in first row and when resize browser window I want 3-column in a row and when again resize browser I want 2-column in a row.Using bootstrap v3.3.4

eg.                              1   2   3   4   5   6

after resizing browser              1   2   3
                                    4   5   6

on last resizing browser window       1   2
                                      3   4 
                                      5   6
These numbers are my column

Comment: you should show us what you try so we can see what the problem is. From this you wrote we can't see anything we can just guess what you should do. Basically that what you want to do is done by that the divs which represent a column assign three class like <div class='col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6' etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">foo bar</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">foo bar</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">foo bar</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">foo bar</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">foo bar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```